# Get attributes of user for title on profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

At the start of my `show.html.erb` file, I have some code for the title, which is as follows:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.full_name + ' (@' + @user.username + ')') %>
```

What I want, is not quite this. I have the `site.com/username` working. My code above is wrong in the way that the title can only grab the name and username of the user signed in. How do I make it universal so that you can visit other profiles and the title is filled in with the name and username of the profile you're visiting?

Comment: What is the name of the instance variable that is used to populate the show page?

Comment: As far as I know, `@user` ?

Comment: Do you have a naming conflict then? If you're saying `@user` should be the target user of that particular show page, but you're observing that it displays the currently logged in user instead, is it possible that variable is being overwritten? What is the name of the var for the currently logged in user?

Comment: I don't think so. The logged in user is `@current_user`. It's giving me an error for `@user.username`, not showing the info of the logged in user. I'm getting a `undefined method `full_name'`. I don't think it's being overwritten, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting user information in `@current_user` you can use `@current_user.user_name` to display the current user name who has logged in.